# Wrap adjacent <p> tags with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to transform HTML to XML with XSLT.

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p class="one">Some paragraph 1.</p>
    <p class="one">Some paragraph 2.</p>
    <p class="one">Some paragraph 3.</p>
    <p class="one">Some paragraph 4.</p>
    <p class="one">Some paragraph 5.</p>
    <h3>Some heading</h3>
    <p class="ipsum">Wrapped paragraph 1.</p>
    <p class="ipsum">Wrapped paragraph 2.</p>
    <p class="ipsum">Wrapped paragraph 3.</p>
    <p class="ipsum">Wrapped paragraph 4.</p>
    <p class="ipsum">Wrapped paragraph 5.</p>
    <h3>Some heading</h3>
    <p class="two">Some paragraph 1.</p>
    <p class="two">Some paragraph 2.</p>
    <p class="two">Some paragraph 3.</p>
    <p class="two">Some paragraph 4.</p>
    <p class="two">Some paragraph 5.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Desired output:

```
<DocumentWrapper>
    <paragraph>Some paragraph 1.</paragraph>
    <paragraph>Some paragraph 2.</paragraph>
    <paragraph>Some paragraph 3.</paragraph>
    <paragraph>Some paragraph 4.</paragraph>
    <paragraph>Some paragraph 5.</paragraph>
    <Heading>Some heading</Heading>
    <WrapperSpecial>
        <SpecialParagraph>Wrapped paragraph 1.</SpecialParagraph>
        <SpecialParagraph>Wrapped paragraph 2.</SpecialParagraph>
        <SpecialParagraph>Wrapped paragraph 3.</SpecialParagraph>
        <SpecialParagraph>Wrapped paragraph 4.</SpecialParagraph>
        <SpecialParagraph>Wrapped paragraph 5.</SpecialParagraph>
    </WrapperSpecial>
    <Heading>Some heading</Heading>
    <paragraph>Some paragraph 1.</paragraph>
    <paragraph>Some paragraph 2.</paragraph>
    <paragraph>Some paragraph 3.</paragraph>
    <paragraph>Some paragraph 4.</paragraph>
    <paragraph>Some paragraph 5.</paragraph>
</DocumentWrapper>
```

I have written following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <DocumentWrapper>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="html/body/*" />
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text></DocumentWrapper>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="p[@class='one']|p[@class='two']">
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><paragraph>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </paragraph>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="h3">
     <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
     <Heading>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </Heading>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which does everything except wrapping `p` tags with `ipsum` class into:

```
<WrapperSpecial>
      <SpecialParagraph>Wrapped paragraph 1.</SpecialParagraph>
      <SpecialParagraph>Wrapped paragraph 2.</SpecialParagraph>
      <SpecialParagraph>Wrapped paragraph 3.</SpecialParagraph>
      <SpecialParagraph>Wrapped paragraph 4.</SpecialParagraph>
      <SpecialParagraph>Wrapped paragraph 5.</SpecialParagraph>
</WrapperSpecial>
```

and I have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way I would approach this sort of problem where you want to do something special with a *group* of adjacent siblings, would be to code things such that we only apply templates initially to the *first* element in each run, and let the template for that element handle the rest of the group.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="html/body" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <DocumentWrapper>
            <!-- apply templates to (a) everything that is _not_ an ipsum para
                 and (b) the first ipsum para in each run -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::p[@class='ipsum'])]
               | p[@class='ipsum']
                 [not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p[@class='ipsum']])]" />
        </DocumentWrapper>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@class='ipsum']">
        <WrapperSpecial>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="group" />
        </WrapperSpecial>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p" mode="group">
        <SpecialParagraph>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </SpecialParagraph>
        <!-- keep processing siblings until we hit something that _isn't_ an
             ipsum para -->
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="group"
             select="following-sibling::*[1][self::p[@class='ipsum']]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- this template will match any p elements except the ipsum ones -->
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <paragraph>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </paragraph>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="h3">
        <Heading>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Heading>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 
<xsl:template match="/">
    <DocumentWrapper>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="html/body/p[@class='one']" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="html/body/h3[1]" />
        <WrapperSpecial>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="html/body/p[@class = 'ipsum']"/>
        </WrapperSpecial>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="html/body/h3[2]" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="html/body/p[@class='two']" />
    </DocumentWrapper>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[@class='one'] | p[@class = 'two']">
    <paragraph>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </paragraph>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[@class='ipsum']">
    <SpecialParagraph>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </SpecialParagraph>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h3">
    <heading>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </heading>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not working for me. Your solution only will work if input file is EXACTLY the same as input file given in the question. It is important that order of the elements in the document is preserved and with your solution (that is using `xsl:apply-templates with selected parts of the document within first template``) order is not preserved if any new elements will be added (for example if I add ``p class="two">...</p>`` on the start of the input document, because in output it will be grouped with other ``p class="two"`` elements).